# Return SQL MAX, with other data in table

Tags: sql, max, sccm

**Table1:**

```
ResourceID
Name0 (STRING)
NumberOfLongons0 (INT)
LastLogon0 (DateTIME)
```

**Table2:**

```
ResourceID
NetbiosName0
```

I am trying to retrieve the following data:

`NetbiosName0`, `Name0`, `NumberOfLogons0`, `LastLogon0` where it shows me `NetbiosName0`, regardless if the other data is present AND the `Name0`/`LastLogon0` where `NumberOfLogons0` is the HIGHEST for the `ResourceID`

**UPDATE:**

Tested the SQL:

```
SELECT T2.ResourceID, T2.Netbios_Name0, T1.Name0, T1.NumberOfLogons0, t1.LastLogon0 
FROM V_R_System T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN v_GS_NETWORK_LOGIN_PROFILE T1 
ON T2.ResourceID = T1.ResourceID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM v_GS_NETWORK_LOGIN_PROFILE 
    WHERE ResourceID = T2.ResourceID AND NumberOfLogons0 > T1.NumberOfLogons0)
```

and got the following results:

```
8435 CLETESTXP-001 NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE 
8435 CLETESTXP-001 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
8435 CLETESTXP-001 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
8435 CLETESTXP-001 TESTAGNA\JBradnan 109 3/22/2012 11:37:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 or later, you can do this:

```
select
  R.ResourceID,
  R.NetbiosName0,
  L.Name0,
  L.LastLogon0
from Table2 as R
outer apply (
  select top (1) 
  -- add WITH TIES
  -- if the largest NumberOfLogons0 value can occur multiple times
    Name0,
    LastLogon0
  from Table1 as L
  where L.ResourceID = R.ResourceID
  order by NumberOfLogons0 desc
) as L
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a single query to do this for multiple resources in a single command:

```
SELECT T2.ResourceID, T2.NetbiosName0, T1.Name0, T1.NumberOfLongons0, t1.LastLogon0
  FROM Table2 T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 T1 ON T2.ResourceID  = T1.ResourceID
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ResourceID = T2.ResourceID AND NumbersOfLogons > T1.NumberOfLogons)
```

If you only need it for a single ResourceID at a time you can do something *like* the following (exact syntax depends on SQL product):

```
SELECT TOP 1 T2.ResourceID, T2.NetbiosName0, T1.Name0, T1.NumberOfLongons0, t1.LastLogon0
  FROM Table2 T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 T1 ON T2.ResourceID  = T1.ResourceID
  WHERE T2.ResourceID = <<ResourceID>> 
  ORDER BY T2.NumberOfLogOns0 DESC
```

Comment: Your on the right track with the first command, I need a list of T2.Netbiosname, showing the T1.Name and T1.LastLogon with the highest T1.NumberOfLogons

When i placed this statement into my query, It returned the data that I wanted, except there are duplicates in the NetbiosName column, as there are unique entries in the Name0 column, but I only want to return the Name0 with the HIGHEST NumberOfLogons.

Comment: If you used the entire statement, include the WHERE NOT EXISTS part, you should have gotten only one result per ResourceID (or, if there are some records with the *same* NumberOfLogOns you would have gotten both duplicates).  If not, could you post sample records and sample results?

Comment: Actual SQL:`SELECT T2.ResourceID, T2.Netbios_Name0, T1.Name0, T1.NumberOfLogons0, t1.LastLogon0 
  FROM V_R_System T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN v_GS_NETWORK_LOGIN_PROFILE T1 ON T2.ResourceID  = T1.ResourceID 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM v_GS_NETWORK_LOGIN_PROFILE WHERE ResourceID = T2.ResourceID AND NumberOfLogons0 > T1.NumberOfLogons0)`
<br>
<br>
**Results:**
8435   CLETESTXP-001   NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE      
 8435   CLETESTXP-001   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE      
 8435   CLETESTXP-001   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      
 8435   CLETESTXP-001   TESTAGNA\JBradnan   109   3/22/2012 11:37:00 AM

Comment: I moved your response into your question where it can be formatted.

Comment: Okay, looking at your sample, you seem to have multiple names for certain resource IDs that are "ties" by virtue of having no logons at all.  In that case, given that you only want one of the three records, which of the names do you want to see in the result set?

Comment: I want to see the Name with the HIGHEST number of Logons in the result set, so in this example, I would expect to see `CLETESTXP-001 TESTAGNA\JBradnan 109 3/22/2012 11:37:00 AM `

Comment: You'll need to change the `> T1.NumberOfLogons)` to `> COALESCE(T1.NumberOfLogons, 0)` to handle your NULLs.  A preferable solution would be to declare the NumberOfLogons column `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` if you feel that correctly models your data.  [Not all SQL engines support COALESCE, but they all have some IFNULL type function to handle this simple case.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question correctly. 
But here is my guess.

```
DECLARE @highest int
SET @Highest = (SELECT MAX(NumberOfLogons0) FROM Table1)
SELECT T2.NetbiosName0, T1.Name0, T1.NumberOfLogons0, T1.LastLogon0
FROM Table1 T1 RIGHT JION Table2 T2
ON T1.ResourceID = T2.ResourceID
WHERE T1.NumberOfLogons0 = @Highest
```

Please leave me a comment if this is not what you want or there is problem in my answer

Comment: Not what I am trying to do, take a look at the Larry's response, and our comments. Perhaps you can provide some assistance. I'm sorry if I havn't been 100% clear in what i want